# How to convert segmentation annotations from coco to yolo format?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, yolo

I was trying to use `yolov7` for instance segmentation on my custom dataset and struggling to convert coco style annotation files to yolo style. I know what annotation files look like for bounding boxes in yolo.

`name_of_class x y width height (in normalized format)`

But what happens, when the COCO JSON file includes fields like `area`, `segmentation` or `rle`? Like below:

```
{
 "id":0,
 "image_id":0,
 "category_id":2,
 "bbox":[305,235,139.303,172.783],
 "area":24069.206,
 "segmentation":[[444.426,257.731,384.96,234.539,351.049,259.643,347.667,260.952,305.122,320.454,359.729,407.321,428.896,382.991,444.426,257.731]],
 "iscrowd":0
}
```

For converting bounding boxes, I use this function:

```
def coco_to_yolo(x1, y1, w, h, image_w, image_h):
    return [((2*x1 + w)/(2*image_w)) , ((2*y1 + h)/(2*image_h)), w/image_w, h/image_h]
```

But how to extend it for segmentation?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? can you share please if so?

Comment: This [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/trian-yolov8-instance-segmentation-on-your-data-6ffa04b2debd) offers a solution. Assuming `coord=(x,y)` and `arr` to be the image, then simply store `cord[0])/arr.shape[0]`